# How to read array data into numpy array from text file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files

I have a text file, `data.txt`, having data in this format:

```
 [[ 1.0   2.0   3.0]
 [1.0    2.0   3.0]
 [1.0    2.0   3.0]
 [1.0    2.0   3.0]]
```

How can I read data in this format into `numpy` array in `jupyter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and is generalizable to other types than `float`:

```
with open("data.txt") as infile:
    np.fromstring( infile.read().replace("[","").replace("]", ""), sep="   ").reshape(-1,3)
```

Note: `np.fromstring` returns a 1d array, I added a reshaping assuming 3 columns.

Comment: OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ee7c43e270be> in <module>()
      2 
      3 with open("data.txt") as infile:
----> 4     np.genfromtxt( infile.read().replace("[","").replace("]", ""))
      5 
      6 


OSError:  1.0   2.0   3.0 
  1.0   2.0   3.0
  1.0   2.0   3.0
  1.0   2.0   3.0 not found.

Comment: @Amit indeed my code contained a bug, I updated it and it now uses `fromstring` instead of `genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

with open("data.txt") as infile:
  my_array = np.array([map(float,line.strip(" []\n").split()) for line in infile.readlines()])
```

Comment: This error comes when i write print(my_array):[<map object at 0x000000B18D17FA20> <map object at 0x000000B18D17FB38>
 <map object at 0x000000B18D17FC50> <map object at 0x000000B18D17FD68>]

Comment: You might want to spend more time learning python.  The output is a list.  Use `print(list(my_array))`

Comment: @AmitGupta I fixed a small error, it should work now